# Displaying Cooldown In Seconds in On_Message in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio

EDIT:
I solved it, I just simply looped the `asyncio.sleep` and set a variable for the cooldown in seconds. :)

I'm new to discord.py and I just started developing a bot.

Most bots like Dank Memer has cooldowns after the `on_message` events happens. (I don't know if Dank Memer is in discord.py or not)

So I want to do the same, but I do not know how to display the cooldown in seconds. (Before you can enter another `on_message` event)

This is part of my code so far: (This is the cooldown)

```
import discord,asyncio #and some other modules
cooldown = []

async def on_message(message):
  # Some Code

  cooldown.append(message.author.id)
  await asyncio.sleep(60)
  cooldown.remove(message.author.id)
```

This code works, it doesn't show how many seconds you have before you can enter another command again.

My code is actually pretty long, so I don't want to rewrite it.
Is there a way to display how many seconds you have got left if the user enters the same command within the cooldown?

Comment: If there is any incorrect wordings and it makes you confused, just ask here. I have a feeling my wording is incorrect.

Comment: Hey Ender, if you found a solution to your problem, please post an answer! This will help others with the same problem better find this question.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Ok I will post it

Comment: @EnderDangered the **EDIT** I solved it, is better at the end of the question rather than at the start in my opinion, but I would even question whether it's needed at all.

Comment: sidenote: consider using the commands extension, because that lets you add cooldowns more simply: `@commands.cooldown(1, SECONDS, commands.BucketType.user)`

Comment: @Eric Jin I thought of it, but I want it to go `on_message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok, I solve it myself.**

At the start you do:

```py
cooldown = []
cooldownSec = 60 # How many seconds
cooldowntime = 0
```

Then, after the events from the `on_message`:

```py
cooldown.append(message.author.id)
for i in range(cooldownSec,-1,-1):
  if i == 0:
    cooldown.remove(message.author.id)
    break
  cooldowntime = i
  asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Put this line of code at the start of the `on_message` function:

```
global cooldowntime
```

Then, at the start of a message event happens:

```py
if message.content.lower().startswith('!test'):
  if message.author.id in cooldown:
      await message.reply(f'You have to wait for {cooldowntime} more seconds before you can use the commands again!')
```

It should work.